# which one is more appropriate? indicate: ... or indicate

Tags: american-english, spoken-english, writing

I'm writing to describe a cartoon, and there's a caption that means "on the road" below the cartoon.
should I write

1: The caption indicates: "On the road".
or
2: The caption indicates "On the road"
or
3: The caption indicates on the road.

I'm just wondering should the colon and the quotation mark in the sentence exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for quotation marks, as this is a direct quote.  Ideally they should be “ and ” (ie “curly-quotes”) but straight quotes " or ' are also okay.

You should have some punctuation before the quote, as the quote is not incorporated as part of the sentence.  I think a comma would be enough, but a colon isn't wrong.

I'm not sure the word “indicates” is the right one.  Perhaps “reads” or “means” might be better.

Comment: Yes. A notice would indicate a fact, e.g. that smoking is forbidden.

Comment: There is a story when Queen Victoria was visiting Dublin, by the River Liffey she asked 'What are those little pieces of paper floating in the water?'. Nobody wanted to explain such an indelicate thing to the Queen until the Duke of Wellington said 'They are notices. ma'am, indicating that bathing is forbidden'.